# After Insert/Update on Table A, IF Conditions Met, Update Record On Table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update

I'm looking to create a trigger where after data is either inserted or updated on Table A, if certain criteria is met, an update will happen to a pre-existing record on Table B.

***Table A***

| TableAId | PersonId | Year | Quarter | Food | Color | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 2022 | 4 | Apple | Red | null |
| 2 | Joe | 2022 | 4 | Carrot | Orange | Yummy |
| 3 | Bill | 2022 | 4 | Celery | null | null |
| 4 | Bill | 2022 | 4 | Apple | Green | Yucky |

***Table B***

| TableBId | PersonId | Year | Quarter | Responded |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 2021 | 3 | Yes |
| 2 | Joe | 2022 | 4 | Yes |
| 3 | Bill | 2022 | 2 | Yes |
| 4 | Bill | 2022 | 4 | Yes |

In verbal logic, the way I want this to work is if there is a record inserted or updated in Table A where `Comment` is null and `Color` is not null, I want to update the Table B `Responded` field to null where the corresponding `PersonId`, `Year` and `Quarter` are equal.

In this specific case, if the 4 records were inserted into Table A, `TableAId` of 1 would meet the criteria of setting off the trigger because it is the only instance where `Comment` is null and `Color` is not null.  What would then need to happen on Table B is we would find the corresponding record of Joe/2022/4 (`PersonId/Year/Quarter`) which in this case is `TableBId` of 2.  We would then change the `Responded` field to null.

In pseudo code:

```
After Insert Into Table A

IF(Any inserted rows contain Comment = null AND color != null)

THEN Update Table B

SET TableB.Responded = null 

WHERE TableA.PersonId = TableB.PersonId AND TableA.Year=TableB.Year AND TableA.Quarter = TableB.Quarter
```

Comment: Please have a go and post when stuck, the official documentation is very good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These should do the trick:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateTableBBasedOnInsert
ON dbo.TableA
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE b
    SET b.Responded=NULL
    FROM TableB b
    JOIN inserted i
        on i.PersonId=b.PersonId AND i.Year=b.Year AND b.Quarter=i.Quarter
    WHERE i.Comment IS NULL AND i.Color IS NOT NULL
END
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateTableBBasedOnUpdate
ON dbo.TableA
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE b
    SET b.Responded=NULL
    FROM TableB b
    JOIN inserted i
        on i.PersonId=b.PersonId AND i.Year=b.Year AND b.Quarter=i.Quarter
    WHERE i.Comment IS NULL AND i.Color IS NOT NULL
END
```

EDIT: As Dale pointed out, these can be combined into a single trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateRows
ON dbo.TableA
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE b
    SET b.Responded=NULL
    FROM TableB b
    JOIN inserted i
        on i.PersonId=b.PersonId AND i.Year=b.Year AND b.Quarter=i.Quarter
    WHERE i.Comment IS NULL AND i.Color IS NOT NULL
END
```

Comment: You know you can create a **single** trigger for both insert and update right? No need for 2...

Comment: You are correct, I've added the combined version too.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).